# how can i change the sql code to VBA ACCESS , Dlookup in Update query

Tags: ms-access, auto-update

I use an update query inside of "access." This query works well while in query-mode; but, when I want to run in VBA mode, the program errors out. The code that produces this error is as follows.

```
UPDATE 
  tblInvoiceS 
SET 
  tblInvoiceS.invoiceSqty = DLookUp(
    "invoiceSqty", "tblinvoiceS", "invoiceSid=forms!frminvoice!invoiceid and invoicesProductcode=forms!frminvoice!lstproduct"
  )+ 1 
WHERE 
  (
    (
      (
        tblInvoiceS.invoiceSproductCode
      )= [Forms] ! [frmInvoice] ! [lstProduct]
    ) 
    AND (
      (tblInvoiceS.invoiceSid)= [forms] ! [frmInvoice] ! [invoiceId]
    )
  );
```

The error that this program produces in VBA mode states that I have a problem in the "Dlookup section." This error concerns `end of statement in "invoiceSqty"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be able to reduce it to:

```
UPDATE 
  tblInvoiceS 
SET 
  invoiceSqty = invoiceSqty + 1
WHERE 
  invoiceSproductCode = [Forms]![frmInvoice]![lstProduct]
  AND
  invoiceSid = [forms]![frmInvoice]![invoiceId]
```

Then, how to "run in VBA"? This is just SQL.

Comment: thank you very much i use with      docmd.runSql     and work!!  So thank you